# OL3 how group feature?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

There are several feature how to grouped into categories depending on the feature?

```
id : "1" 
lat : 88.777 
lon : 88.777 
name : "Name company 1" 
cat_id: "12" 

id : "2" 
lat : 77.777 
lon : 77.777 
name : "Name company 2" 
cat_id: "30" 

id : "3" 
lat : 99.777 
lon : 99.777 
name : "Name company 3" 
cat_id: "12"
```

**cat_id = name category**

There are several features how grouped by category?
Depending on the category feature.

the logic of something like that:

```
if(value['Category'] == '12'){ 
 //put feature in a group of 12
} 
else if(value['Category'] == '30'){ 
 //put feature in a group of 30
}
```

Comment: It is not clear for me what did you mean, please describe your task more precisely.

Comment: @Drnextgis 

I unfortunately do not know the English language. Sorry.
I need to group or add to the collection by category(cat_id) features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of iterating through vector layer's features:

```
var groups = {};

layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature) {
    var cat_id = feature.getProperties().cat_id;
    groups[cat_id] = groups[cat_id] || [];
    groups[cat_id].push(feature);
});
```